# Some @media querys works, others not

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Im using bootstrap and own style.css.

I dont know some @media works some doesn't.

Code:

```
    .col-md-4.acompanhantes {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    float: left;
    }
    @media (max-width: 1200px){...}
    @media (max-width:1000px){...}
    @media (max-width:992px){
    .col-md-4.acompanhantes {width:50%;}
    }
    @media (max-width: 767px){...}
    @media (max-width: 700px){...}
    @media (max-width:550px;){
    .col-md-4.acompanhantes {width:100%;}
    }
    @media (max-width:480px;){...}
```

Code on max-width:550 does not work, may some conflict with bootstrapm, i dont know.

For exemple ".col-md-4.acompanhantes" does not work on max-width:550 but works on max-width:992px.

Thanks

Comment: What codes? All you've provided are empty media queries. What CSS rules are you trying to change, exactly?

Comment: Also, you have a typo in the last media query - `x` instead of `px`.

Comment: I updated the code, macbem the code was right on css, just i wrote wrong here!

Comment: You have a `;` after `max-width:550px`. That makes the declaration invalid, causing it to be ignored entirely.

Comment: Works Peter, wow, sometimes we are looking for some many problems and the most simple was correct :P thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a semicolon just after `max-width: 550px`, which makes your media query fail because of invalid syntax.

Try removing it to fix this issue.